# JS-based policy option missing in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to create a JS-based policy in Keycloak, and the documentation states:

> To create a new JavaScript-based policy, select JavaScript in the
>   dropdown list in the upper right corner of the policy listing.

but when I go to `MyClient->Authorization->Policies` and click the `CreatePolicy` dropdown in the top right corner, there is no "JS-based policy" alternative.

Am I missing something here? The only policy in the list is the `Default Policy` which is of type `js`, which also confuses me since that means JS-based policies should be available.

I'm running Keycloak `10.0.0`, but I've also tried with version `9.0.3`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to enable scripting features: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#profiles

```
-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled
```

Then you will be able to play with Javascript in the Keycloak console. And yes, `upload_scripts` is deprecated feature, so keep it in the mind - you will need `jar` deployment for that in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of **Keycloak (>=18.0.0)** you'll need to build the instance with "**scripts**" feature enabled.

I'm doing it with environment variable:

```
...
ENV KC_FEATURES=account-api,account2,authorization,client-policies,impersonation,docker,scripts,upload_scripts
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build
...
```

My full Dockerfile to build the keycloak image, if someone interested:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0 as builder

ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_FEATURES=account-api,account2,authorization,client-policies,impersonation,docker,scripts,upload_scripts
ENV KC_DB=postgres
# Install custom providers
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi/releases/download/2.5.3/keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar -o /opt/keycloak/providers/keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build
USER root
RUN chown root:root -R /opt/keycloak

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0
COPY --from=builder --chown=keycloak:root /opt/keycloak /opt/keycloak
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "--verbose", "start", "--import-realm", "--http-relative-path=/auth"]
```

You can also pass features as parameter: `--features=`

**[Update]** Unfortunately, keycloak removed support for upload JS scripts from admin starting version 18. So, you'll need to deploy them as .jar(zip) files. It works, but makes the development and testing of JS modules slower.

See [Enabled/Disable features documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/features) for more details.

Comment: Kostanos do you have an example of how this might look?

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_script_providers

I followed this, confirmed everything was there in the `.zip`. But I am not seeing the policies in the Keycloak dashboard.

Comment: you need to enable the policy in admin too (once you added a script)